# El diseño adaptable (responsive design) ya funciona en los sitios internacionales

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, anuncios, sitios-internacionales

Este anuncio es una traducción de [Responsive design for international sites has been released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-will-be-released-soon), publicado en Meta.SE por nuestro CM Nicolas Chabanovsky.

---

**Me complace anunciar que los sitios internacionales recibirán el nuevo responsive design el martes 25 de septiembre.**

La semana pasada todos los sitios beta y no diseñados tuvieron el nuevo tema:

> Algunas cosas a tener en cuenta:
>
> - La navegación izquierda está activa en la mayoría de las páginas (pero puede ser "colapsada" en un menú visitando las preferencias de su sitio - [instrucciones aquí](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/new-stock-theme-roll-out)).
> - El responsive design está activo, lo que permite que el sitio se ajuste a medida que cambian los anchos del navegador - sin desplazamiento lateral (aunque algunas páginas aún no se han actualizado). Por ahora, si prefiere el desplazamiento, puede desactivarlo haciendo clic en el enlace "desactivar responsiveness" en el pie de página.
> - El subrayado de enlaces está activo. En un esfuerzo por hacer más visibles los enlaces, ahora se están subrayando.
>
> ---
>
> ...
>
> La unificación del diseño también nos permite mejorar más fácilmente las funciones existentes, como la [observación de etiquetas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312180/354333), y desarrollar nuevas funciones que se han solicitado durante mucho tiempo, como las [listas de preguntas personalizadas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer), que actualmente se están probando. Nos encantaría tener más características para todos ustedes y eso es más fácil cuando pasamos más tiempo trabajando en las nuevas características y menos tiempo aplastando los errores que causan porque tenemos más de 60 diseños de sitios muy diferentes.
>
> Esto se explica en una entrada en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314799/why-we-initiated-the-latest-round-of-design-changes-and-the-role-of-meta) si quieres más detalles.

Como parte de la red de Stack Exchange, los sitios internacionales pronto tendrán el nuevo tema también con la única diferencia: no tendremos periodo de prueba, así que el tema estará disponible para todos.

Si encuentras algún error y quieres reportarlo, por favor asegúrate de que los errores sean publicados como respuestas a esta pregunta. Si tiene inquietudes generales, por favor deje sus comentarios sobre el [post de MSE existente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/).

¡Por favor, siéntase libre de publicar sus comentarios en [la comunidad internacional aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315856/responsive-design-for-international-sites-will-be-released-soon)!

Comment: Un poco fuera del plazo previsto, pero ya es una realidad.

Comment: ¿Quién será el malvado que lo tenía secuestrado? :) Quizás publicado sería más apropiado.

Comment: Pienso que es mejor que se llame *Diseño responsivo* en lugar de *Responsive Design*.

Comment: @iBug yo iría por [_adaptable_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/5372/1674).

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, tienes razón. Lo harías ahora? (porque no lo puedo editar)

Comment: @iBug hecho : )

Answer (score 5):

[Enlace a la publicación en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316297/384394)

---

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

El la pestaña de perfil en [Stack Overflow Meta en español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com) el texto de *personas alcanzadas* sale del contenedor de la página.

[image: Imagen mostrando como el texto sale de su contenedor]

No pasa lo mismo en los metas de los otros sitios internacionales

Lo probé en:

- Firefox Quantum 62.0.3
- Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100
- Safari 12.0 (14606.1.36.1.9)

Todos en macOS Mojave 10.14

Comment: He comprobado en los metas en ruso y portugues y no ocurre. El problema es que el texto (_personas alcanzadas_) es más largo en español que en los otros idiomas (en portugues ese texto es _personas ajudadas_). Veremos si lo resuelven o si no tal vez podamos buscar un texto equivalente y que sea mas corto.

Comment: No se como no se me ocurrió verlo en el perfil de alguien mas, creo que ya era muy tarde ayer. Lo más probable es que tengamos que solucionarlo cambiando la traducción...

Comment: y qué bueno lo de _Si por otro lado quieres enviarme spam puedes contactarme a username@example.com ;)_ :P

Comment: Hay que cuidarse de los _bots_ @fedorqui :D

Answer (score 4):

[Enlace a la publicación en Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315972/384394)

---

> [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

En [la lista de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review), la palabra *publicaciones* sale de su contenedor

[image: Palabra saliendo de su contenedor]

Lo probé en:

- Firefox Quantum 62.0.2
- Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100
- Safari 12.0 (13606.2.11)

Todos en macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: ¡Lo he notado y lo he reportado! Gracias.